# Work on laravel framework togater on single project

Tags: laravel-5

We are 3 members who wants to work together on a single project

looking for a solution to do so.without overwriting the existing code

Comment: Did you try any versioning software like git?

Comment: i tried but it will overweight the code

Answer (score 0):

Git is your best friend for this problem. Simply nominate the lead developer and let that person create the base application and commit it to the respository to be shared by you all.
The other two members can then clone the repository created by the lead. Each of you will then created 3 branches preferrably in your names where each of your individual work will be saved. After code review of your implementations, you can vote which ones to adopt and merge to the master branch (i.e. the original one created by the lead)
For more info, visit https://www.atlassian.com/git